# Unable to Select Specified Database in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

when i open my project in localhost initially its loaded and insert values into database table. But second time it shows unable to loading error.

[image]

My xampp also shows error when once loaded this site.. One day i loaded this site after the day this error continously shows..

[image]

Comment: Check your database configuration.

Comment: This site already working more than 30 days.. But two days before only this problem occured.. And also when i start my xampp it shows some port error

Comment: I think there will be some port conflict.

Comment: @lolka_bolka , yes, how to rectify this?..

Comment: Check this https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Security_Guide/s1-server-ports.html or this http://superuser.com/questions/529830/get-a-list-of-open-ports-in-linux and looking for service what is hold the 80 or 3306